# Count arrays that make unique sets

Tags: combinatorics, fastest-code

This question has a similar set up to [Find an array that fits a set of sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/174252/find-an-array-that-fits-a-set-of-sums) although is quite different in its goals.

Consider an array `A` of length `n`. The array contains only positive integers.  For example `A = (1,1,2,2)`.  Let us define `f(A)` as the set of sums of all the non-empty contiguous subarrays of `A`. In this case `f(A) = {1,2,3,4,5,6}`.  The steps to produce `f(A)`  are as follows:

The subarrays of `A` are `(1), (1), (2), (2), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (1,1,2), (1,2,2), (1,1,2,2)`. Their respective sums are `1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6`. The set you get from this list is therefore `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`.

We call an array `A` **unique** if there is no other array `B` of the same length such that `f(A) = f(B)`, except for the array `A` reversed. As an example, `f((1,2,3)) = f((3,2,1)) = {1,2,3,5,6}` but there is no other array of length `3` that produces the same set of sums.

We will only consider arrays where the elements are either a given integer `s` or `s+1`. E.g. if `s=1` the arrays would only contain `1` and `2`.

**Task**

The task, for a given `n` and `s` is to count the number of unique arrays of that length.  You can assume that `s` is between `1` and `9`.

You should not count the reverse of an array as well as the array itself.

**Examples**

`s = 1`, the answer is always `n+1`.

`s = 2`, the answers counting from `n = 1` up are:

```
2,3,6,10,20,32,52,86
```

`s = 8`, the answers counting from `n = 1` up are:

```
2,3,6,10,20,36,68,130
```

**Score**

For a given `n`, your code should output the answer for all values of `s` from `1` to `9`. Your score is the highest value of `n` for which this completes in one minute.

**Testing**

I will need to run your code on my ubuntu machine so please include as detailed instructions as possible for how to compile and run your code.

**Leaderboard**

- **n = 24** by Anders Kaseorg in **Rust** (34 seconds)
- **n = 16** by Ourous in **Clean** (36 seconds)
- **n = 14** by JRowan in **Common Lisp** (49 seconds)

Comment: So if s=8 then its an array of all possible combinations of 8 and 9, nothing else?

Comment: @JRowan No. You don't count any of those arrays that have the same set of sums as some other array.

Comment: This part i am a little confused about We will only consider arrays where the elements are either a given integer s or s+1. E.g. if s=1 the arrays would only contain 1 and 2.  So if n is 2 and s is 3 what would the arrays to test be?

Comment: what about [3,3] and im currently removing the reverse of the lists eg. [3,4]->[4,3]

Comment: @JRowan (Corrected) If n = 2 and s = 3 the possible arrays are [3,3], [3,4], [4,3] and [4,4]. You can then remove the reverses as you say.

Comment: s and n: what is s ... I not understand good...

Comment: Why for the example Input: n=4, S = (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13), output is X = (3, 5, 1, 4) ???? {3,5,4} it is one subset of X and 3+5+4= 12 is not in S

Comment: that S and its result X are your example in the other code-golf tournament of the same problem

Comment: @RosLuP Firstly, you meant to post that on [the other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/174252), and secondly, [3, 5, 4] is a [subset but not a subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26568560) of [3, 5, 1, 4].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), n ≈ 24

Requires nightly Rust for the convenient `reverse_bits` feature.  Compile with `rustc -O unique.rs` and run with (e.g.) `./unique 24`.

```rust
#![feature(reverse_bits)]
use std::{collections::HashMap, env, mem, process};

type T = u32;
const BITS: u32 = mem::size_of::<T>() as u32 * 8;

fn main() {
    let args = env::args().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    assert!(args.len() == 2);
    let n: u32 = args[1].parse().unwrap();
    assert!(n > 0);
    assert!(n <= BITS);
    let mut unique = (2..=9).map(|_| HashMap::new()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut sums = vec![0 as T; n as usize];
    for a in 0 as T..=!0 >> (BITS - n) {
        if a <= a.reverse_bits() >> (BITS - n) {
            for v in &mut sums {
                *v = 0;
            }
            for i in 0..n {
                let mut bit = 1;
                for j in i..n {
                    bit <<= a >> j & 1;
                    sums[(j - i) as usize] |= bit;
                }
            }
            for s in 2..=9 {
                let mut sums_s =
                    vec![0 as T; ((n + (n - 1) * s) / BITS + 1) as usize].into_boxed_slice();
                let mut pos = 0;
                let mut shift = 0;
                let mut lo = 0;
                let mut hi = 0;
                for &v in &sums {
                    lo |= v << shift;
                    if BITS - shift < n {
                        hi |= v >> (BITS - shift);
                    }
                    shift += s;
                    if shift >= BITS {
                        shift -= BITS;
                        sums_s[pos] = lo;
                        pos += 1;
                        lo = hi;
                        hi = 0;
                    }
                }
                if lo != 0 || hi != 0 {
                    sums_s[pos] = lo;
                    pos += 1;
                    if hi != 0 {
                        sums_s[pos] = hi;
                    }
                }
                unique[s as usize - 2]
                    .entry(sums_s)
                    .and_modify(|u| *u = false)
                    .or_insert(true);
            }
        }
    }
    let mut counts = vec![n + 1];
    counts.extend(
        unique
            .iter()
            .map(|m| m.values().map(|&u| u as T).sum::<T>())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    );
    println!("{:?}", counts);
    process::exit(0); // Avoid running destructors.
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. It completes for n = 25 in about 90 seconds. But the main problem is that it uses 70% of my 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I have suddenly got worried about something. Are you checking that the arrays are unique with respect to all other possible arrays, or just arrays with values `s` and `s+1` in them?

Comment: @Anush Yes, I traded some memory usage for speed. I’m counting arrays that are unique w.r.t. other arrays with values `s` and `s + 1` (since you said those are the only arrays we will consider), although it’s not immediately obvious whether that would make a difference.

Comment: I think I will need to work  this out tomorrow. The arrays 1,1,2,2 and 1,1,1,3 both give the set of sums 1,2,3,4,5,6.  However the former is not unique amongst arrays with only 1 and 2 so I am a little confused if it makes a difference now.

Comment: @Anush It does make a difference: the sums of [1, 2, 2, 2] are unique among arrays with 1 and 2 of length 4, but equal to the sums of [1, 1, 2, 3].

Comment: OK so I will leave this question as is and ask another one where the arrays have to be unique over all possible arrays soon. However first I need to work out how to solve it myself !

Answer (score 2):

**Common Lisp SBCL, N = 14**

call function (goahead n s)

```
    (defun sub-lists(l m &optional(x 0)(y 0))
  (cond; ((and(= y (length l))(= x (length l)))nil)
        ((= y (length l))m)
        ((= x (length l))(sub-lists l m 0(1+ y)))
    (t (sub-lists l (cons(loop for a from x to (+ x y)

             when (and(nth (+ x y)l)(nth a l)(< (+ x y)(length l)))
                ;   while (nth a l)
             ;while(and(< (+ x y)(length l))(nth a l))
                    collect (nth a l))m) (1+ x)y))
    ))
(defun permutations(size elements)
  (if (zerop size)'(())
 (mapcan (lambda (p)
                    (map 'list (lambda (e)
                           (cons e p))
                         elements))
     (permutations (1- size) elements))))
(defun remove-reverse(l m)
  (cond ((endp l)m)
    ((member (reverse (first l))(rest l) :test #'equal)(remove-reverse (rest l)m))
    (t (remove-reverse (rest l)(cons (first l)m)))))
(defun main(n s)
  (let((l (remove-reverse (permutations n `(,s ,(1+ s)))nil)))

  (loop for x in l
     for j = (remove 'nil (sub-lists x nil))
       collect(sort (make-set(loop for y in j
        collect (apply '+ y))nil)#'<)
     )
  ))
(defun remove-dups(l m n)
  (cond ((endp l)n)
        ((member (first l) (rest l) :test #'equal)(remove-dups(rest l)(cons (first l) m) n))
    ((member (first l) m :test #'equal)(remove-dups(rest l)m n))
    (t(remove-dups (rest l) m (cons (first l) n))))

  )
(defun goahead(n s)
  (loop for a from 1 to s
  collect(length (remove-dups(main n a)nil nil))))
(defun make-set (L m)
  "Returns a set from a list. Duplicate elements are removed."
  (cond ((endp L) m)
    ((member (first L) (rest L)) (make-set (rest L)m))
    ( t (make-set (rest L)(cons (first l)m)))))
```

here is the run times

```
CL-USER> (time (goahead 14 9))
Evaluation took:
  34.342 seconds of real time
  34.295000 seconds of total run time (34.103012 user, 0.191988 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.263 seconds GC time, and 34.032 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.86% CPU
  103,024,254,028 processor cycles
  1,473,099,744 bytes consed

(15 1047 4893 6864 7270 7324 7328 7328 7328)
CL-USER> (time (goahead 15 9))
Evaluation took:
  138.639 seconds of real time
  138.511089 seconds of total run time (137.923824 user, 0.587265 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.630 seconds GC time, and 137.882 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.91% CPU
  415,915,271,830 processor cycles
  3,453,394,576 bytes consed

(16 1502 8848 13336 14418 14578 14594 14594 14594)
```

Comment: How do I run this? Do I copy your code into a file and call it from `sbcl` somehow?

Comment: I use emacs and slime but you could put it in a file say test.lisp and in sbcl promp at your directory call (load "test.lisp") and then call the function how i have it at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux)

Certainly not the most efficient approach, but I'm interested in seeing how well a naive by-value filter does.

That said, there's still a bit of improvement to be made using this method.

```
module main
import StdEnv, Data.List, System.CommandLine

f l = sort (nub [sum t \\ i <- inits l, t <- tails i])

Start w
	# ([_:args], w) = getCommandLine w
	= case map toInt args of
		[n] = map (flip countUniques n) [1..9]
		_ = abort "Wrong number of arguments!"

countUniques 1 n = inc n
countUniques s n = length uniques
where
	lists = [[s + ((i >> p) bitand 1) \\ p <- [0..dec n]] \\ i <- [0..2^n-1]]
	pairs = sortBy (\(a,_) (b,_) = a < b) (zip (map f lists, lists))
	groups = map (snd o unzip) (groupBy (\(a,_) (b,_) = a == b) pairs)
	uniques = filter (\section = case section of [a, b] = a == reverse b; [_] = True; _ = False) groups
```

Place in a file named `main.icl`, or change the top line to `module <your_file_name_here>`.

Compile with `clm -h 1500m -s 50m -fusion -t -IL Dynamics -IL StdEnv -IL Platform main`.

You can get the version TIO (and myself) use from the link in the heading, or a more recent one from [here](https://clean.cs.ru.nl/Download_Clean).

Comment: I don't think this code gives the right output. I tried it with s=8 and it gives [9,86,126,130,130,130,130,130,130]

Comment: @Anush hmm I know I tested it. I'll see if I changed anything between that and the posted one, give me a few hours and I can do it on my break.

Comment: @Anush Why are you providing `s`? In the question you state "**For a given n**, your code should output the answer for all values of s from 1 to 9."

Comment: I think that is what you call a brain freeze on my part  :)  I will time your code now.