# Count arrays that are really unique

Tags: combinatorics, fastest-code

This is a follow up to [Count arrays that make unique sets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/count-arrays-that-make-unique-sets) . The significant difference is the definition of uniqueness.

Consider an array `A` of length `n`. The array contains only positive integers.  For example `A = (1,1,2,2)`.  Let us define `f(A)` as the set of sums of all the non-empty contiguous subarrays of `A`. In this case `f(A) = {1,2,3,4,5,6}`.  The steps to produce `f(A)`  are as follows:

The subarrays of `A` are `(1), (1), (2), (2), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (1,1,2), (1,2,2), (1,1,2,2)`. Their respective sums are `1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6`. The set you get from this list is therefore `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`.

We call an array `A` **unique** if there is no other array `B` of the same length such that `f(A) = f(B)`, except for the array `A` reversed. As an example, `f((1,2,3)) = f((3,2,1)) = {1,2,3,5,6}` but there is no other array of length `3` that produces the same set of sums.

**Task**

The task, for a given `n` and `s` is to count the number of unique arrays of that length.  You can assume that `s` is between `1` and `9`. You only need to count arrays where the elements are either a given integer `s` or `s+1`. E.g. if `s=1` the arrays you are counting only contain `1` and `2`.  However, the definition of uniqueness is with respect to any other array of the same length. As a concrete example `[1, 2, 2, 2]` is **not** unique as it gives the same set of sums as `[1, 1, 2, 3]`.

You should count the reverse of an array as well as the array itself (as long as the array is not a palindrome of course).

**Examples**

`s = 1`, the answers for n = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 are:

```
4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6
```

For `s = 1`, the unique arrays of length 4 are

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

`s = 2`, the answers for n = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 are:

```
4, 8, 16, 32, 46, 69, 121, 177
```

An example of an array that is not unique with `s = 2` is:

```
(3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3).
```

This has the same set of sums as both of: `(3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3)` and `(3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3)`.

`s = 8`, the answers for n = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 are:

```
4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 120, 244, 472
```

**Score**

For a given `n`, your code should output the answer for all values of `s` from `1` to `9`. Your score is the highest value of `n` for which this completes in one minute.

**Testing**

I will need to run your code on my ubuntu machine so please include as detailed instructions as possible for how to compile and run your code.

**Leaderboard**

- **n = 13** by Christian Sievers in **Haskell** (42 seconds)

Comment: How much memory are we allowed to consume?

Comment: @BlackOwlKai My machine has 8GB so I guess 6GB is safe?

Comment: I think the last number in the examples should be 472 instead of 427.

Comment: @ChristianSievers Thank you. Fixed now.

Comment: What is `s`? What does it represent?

Comment: @Gigaflop "You only need to count arrays where the elements are either a given integer s or s+1. E.g. if s=1 the arrays you are counting only contain 1 and 2. "

Comment: @Anush Did you notice the updated version? I think it's worth redoing the timing. Of course I'll understand when you won't: we all have other things to do.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import Data.List (tails)
import qualified Data.IntSet as S
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (write)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

orig:: Int -> Int -> M.Map S.IntSet (Maybe Int)
orig n s = M.fromListWith (\ _ _ -> Nothing) 
               [(sums l, Just $! head l) | 
                   l <- replicateM n [s, s+1],
                   l <= reverse l ]

sums :: [Int] -> S.IntSet
sums l = S.fromList [ hi-lo | (lo:r) <- tails $ scanl (+) 0 l, hi <- r ]

construct :: Int -> Int -> S.IntSet -> [Int]
construct n start set =
   setmax `seq` setmin `seq` setv `seq`
   [ weight r | r <- map (start:) $ constr (del start setlist)
                                           (V.singleton start)
                                           (n-1)
                                           (setmax - start),
                r <= reverse r ]
  where
    setlist = S.toList set
    setmin = S.findMin set
    setmax = S.findMax set
    setv = V.modify (\v -> mapM_ (\p -> write v p True) setlist)
                    (V.replicate (1+setmax) False)

    constr :: [Int] -> V.Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
    constr m _ 0 _ | null m    = [[]]
                   | otherwise = []
    constr m a i x =
         [ v:r | v <- takeWhile (x-(i-1)*setmin >=) setlist,
                 V.all (V.unsafeIndex setv . (v+)) a,
                 let new = V.cons v $ V.map (v+) a,
                 r <- (constr (m \\\ new) $! new) (i-1) $! (x-v) ]
 
del x [] = []
del x yl@(y:ys) = if x==y then ys else if y<x then y : del x ys else yl

(\\\) = V.foldl (flip del)

weight l = if l==reverse l then 1 else 2

count n s = sum ( map value [ x | x@(_, Just _) <- M.toList $ orig n s]
                      `using` parBuffer 128 rseq )
  where 
    value (sms, Just st) = uniqueval $ construct n st sms
    uniqueval [w] = w
    uniqueval _   = 0


main = do
  [ n ] <- getArgs
  mapM_ print ( map (count (read n)) [1..9]
                    `using` parBuffer 2 r0 )
```

The `orig` function creates all the lists of length `n` with entries `s` or `s+1`, keeps them if they come before their reverse, computes their sublist `sums` and puts those in a map which also remembers the first element of the list. When the same set of sums is found more than once, the first element is replaced with `Nothing`, so we know we don't have to look for other ways to get these sums.

The `construct` function searches for lists of given length and given starting value that have a given set of sublist sums. Its recursive part `constr` follows essentially the same logic as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174303), but has an additional argument giving the sum the remaining list entries need to have. This allows to stop early when even the smallest possible values are too big to get this sum, which gave a massive performance improvement. Further big improvements were obtained by moving this test to an earlier place (version 2) and by replacing the list of current sums by a `Vector` (version 3 (broken) and 4 (with additional strictness)). The latest version does the set membership test with a lookup table and adds some more strictness and parallelization.

When `construct` has found a list that gives the sublist sums and is smaller than its reverse, it could return it, but we are not really interested in it. It would almost be enough to just return `()` to indicate its existence, but we need to know if we have to count it twice (because it is not a palindrome and we'll never handle its reverse). So we put 1 or 2 as its `weight` into the list of results.

The function `count` puts these parts together. For each set of sublist sums (coming from `orig`) that was unique amongst the lists containing only `s` and `s+1`, it calls `value`, which calls `construct` and, via `uniqueval`, checks if there is only one result. If so, that is the weight we have to count, otherwise the set of sums was not unique and zero is returned. Note that due to lazyness, `construct` will stop when it has found two results.

The `main` function handles IO and the loop of `s` from 1 to 9.

#### Compiling and Running

On debian this needs the packages `ghc`, `libghc-vector-dev` and `libghc-parallel-dev`. Save the program in a file `prog.hs` and compile it with `ghc -threaded -feager-blackholing -O2 -o prog prog.hs`. Run with `./prog <n> +RTS -N` where `<n>` is the array length for which we want to count the unique arrays.

Comment: This code is pretty amazing (and short!). If you could add some explanation I am sure people would love to understand what you have done.

Comment: Your new version doesn't compile for me. I get https://bpaste.net/show/c96c4cbdc02e

Comment: Sorry, deleting and pasting bigger code is so uncomfortable that I sometimes just change the few lines by hand. Of course I made a mistake... Fixed now (I hope), and added another improvement, this time only for a few percent. The other changes were much more important.